# Ember 3.16 Octane - Component not displaying in Application.hbs

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I used ember generate to create a header component for a youtube video I am following. I have a few questions -

1. When I ran ember generate component header, the terminal responded with creating the header.hbs file in  app>components, but then skips header.js in app/components. I manually created a header.js file in that directory and if I do an alert() in the js file it works.
2. I have the following code in my header.hbs file.

```
<h1>Hello There!</h1>

{{yield}}
```

In my application.hbs file :

```
<Header/>


{{outlet}}
```

thoughts, suggestions? Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: You mean, the component is not rendering in spite of the setup you mentioned above? If so, can you share the header.js code? coz, there should not be an empty component's js file.

Comment: if you have a `header.js`  you need to export a component. But you can remove it. You dont need the `.js` file in octane. Does it work when you remove the `.js` file? Do you get any kind of build error? what do you see in the ember inspector?

Comment: @Lux That was my problem! I didn't grasp that the js file needed to be export a component.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain this a bit. Basically there are 4 kinds of components in ember.

**without a `.js` file**:

When you invoke a component ember will first look up the component class. When it does *not* find such a class the behavior depends on the optional feature `template-only-glimmer-components`. This is by default enabled for new octane apps.

If it *is* enabled ember will look up the component template based on some standard rules and use it, but there will be *no* backing class. That is pretty nice. This is also basically what you get in a octane app when you do `ember g component my-component`.

When `template-only-glimmer-components` is disabled then an *implicit* classic component class will automagically be created and used together with the correct template. You don't want this behavior. If you still have it you can migrate away from it by 1) creating a `.js` file for every component and then 2) enabling `template-only-glimmer-components`.

**with a `.js` file**

When a `js` file is found ember will get the `default` export of that module. Then it will look up the correct component manager. This actually depends on that export: `setComponentManager` should have been called on it. This is usually done in a base class as `@ember/component` or `@glimmer/component`.
But you *can* also write your own custom component manager.

Basically ember will then also look up the template based on that component. A public API for this is proposed in [this](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/454) RFC, but currently a private API is used for the so called *template co-location* where you place your `.hbs` file next to your `.js` file with the same name and just a different extension. This is the default in octant. Here a ember internal build-step in `ember-cli` basically adds your template to the `.js` file and uses that API. You can also see the result in a browser debugger. So when there is no default export then ember can not find your template.